# Construcción extraña: objeto = funcion1() && funcion2() ¿Posible?

Tags: c#

acabo de encontrarme en una documentación una construcción como esta:

```
var pose = Body.LeftHand.Near(Body.Head) && Body.LeftArm.Bended(90);
```

`pose`es una objeto que debe crearse a partir de la expresión de la derecha.
¿Tiene sentido? Soy algo novato con c# y nunca había visto algo así.

Comment: *¿Posible?*: ¿Lo has probado?

Comment: Mira la edicion que hice, quiza te ayude a entender por que no se puede hacer asi.

Comment: @rnd Sí, comprendo que no se puede hacer así, de ahí mi duda al verlo, jamás había visto una construcción así en otro lenguaje. Gracias por gastar el tiempo probando.

Comment: De nada, recuerda marcar una respuesta como aceptada si crees que soluciono tu problema (no es obligatorio, pero deseable) salu2

Comment: @sstan No existe como tal, no se refiere a una biblioteca existente. Lo único que puedo probar me devuelve boleanos (como es de esperar). Mi duda básicamente es si algo así tiene sentido en c#.

Comment: Esa expresión que dices se suele llamar operador en conrtocircuito. Es útil para ahorrar comprobaciones ya que si la primera condición no se cumple no se siguen evaluando las siguientes pues ya va a dar falso. Java por ejemplo es igual. La diferencia creo que java empieza evaluando por la izquierda y c# por la derecha si no me equivoco.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n: Ambos comienzan por la izquierda.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n no es _operador en conrtocircuito_ sino **operador de circuito corto**

Comment: @rnd Es un **operador en cortocircuito** o como pone en la documentación de java **"short-circuiting"**: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html La 'n' que sobra esta claro que es un error al escribir.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n revisa tu ingles, esta mal traducido decir "de cortocircuito" y esta peor sostener el error https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluaci%C3%B3n_de_cortocircuito

Comment: @rnd Creo que al que le hace falta revisar el inglés es a tí. Mira la página de msdn ya que hablamos de c# [enlace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx) y mira la página de wordreference [enlace] (http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=short-circuit) o el mismo traductor de google para ver que antes de meterte con alguien hay que dar ejemplo y comprobarlo.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n ya se que el traductor de google da eso, pero esta mal traducido. Y no me meti con nadie. Sigue con tu pensamiento si quieres.

Comment: @rnd También te he puesto a wordreference. La wikipedia no es palabra de Dios, hay que tomar con precaución lo que leas ahí, pero no voy a discutir más, cada uno que lo llame como quiera.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `pose` es una **objeto** que debe crearse a partir de la expresión de la derecha. ¿Tiene sentido? Soy algo novato con c# y nunca había visto algo así.

Eso depende, esa expresión es valida siempre y cuando ambos operandos sean de tipo `bool`. El resultado de la misma también sera de tipo `bool`

Es equivalente a hacer esto

```
var pose = false; 

if (Body.LeftHand.Near(Body.Head) && Body.LeftArm.Bended(90)) {
   pose = true;
}
```

## EDIT

*de los comentarios*

> Lo todavía más curioso del asunto es que ambas juntas **deben devolver un solo objeto**.

Esto no es posible, esta expresion siempre devolverá un resultado `bool`, suponiendo que `Blended` retorna un objeto y `Near` un booleano, podrias hacer algo asi, pero ten en cuenta que el valor final puede ser nulo y deberias hacer las validaciones apropiadas antes de utilizar el objeto.

```
var pose = Body.LeftHand.Near(Body.Head) ? Body.LeftArm.Bended(90) : null;
```

Enconces pose tendra el tipo de datos retornado por `Bended` y con valor null si `Near` retorna `false`.

Nota adicional, si alguno de los metodos no retornase tipo de dato `bool` esta expresion no puede compilar y va a dar el error:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'object'

O similar.

Comment: Sí, eso sería lo normal y la forma que yo conocía. Pero la idea es que `pose` sea un objeto con el que luego trabajar.

Comment: No puedes hacerlo asi entonces, el operador && retorna una tipo de dato bool

Comment: @mjota explicame un poco como quieres pasarle el objeto, Body.LeftArm.Bended(90) retorna un objeto ? o ambas funciones?

Comment: Lo todavía más curioso del asunto es que ambas **juntas** deben devolver un solo objeto. 
Doy por hecho que es un errata y que esta construcción no tiene sentido. He buscado info en manuales e internet y no he encontrado nada.

Comment: Si la función `Body.LeftHand.Near(Body.Head)` devuelve un booleano y la función `Body.LeftArm.Bended(90)` devuelve un booleano, la construcción del principio es perfectamente válida pues `boolean && boolean` devuelve un `boolean` también, que es el tipo final de `var`

Comment: @Awes0meM4n correcto, pero mojta explico que queria retornar el valor de la funcion `Blended` el cual era un objeto, por eso hice esa aclaracion.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Sí, claro. Pero en este caso no devuelven boleanos.

Comment: Yo es que no veo que en ningún momento haya dicho eso @mjota. Dice que en una documentación encontró esa expresión y no sabe si era correcta, para mi es simplemente una pregunta: ¿Está la mano izquierda cerca de la cabeza y está el brazo izquierdo doblado 90 (grados entiendo)?. Si es así `pose` es `true` y con eso se puede trabajar luego igual, pues java lo transforma a un `Boolean` en caso necesario.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n lo dijo en los comentarios.

Comment: Por favor dime en cual porque lo he leído 3 veces ya todo y no lo veo.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n lo habra borrado. no esta XD, no es para tanto igual, todo el punto quedo aclarado.

Comment: Lo mejor sería que pusiera la parte de código del método `Body.LeftArm.Bended(arg)` y dónde se usa `pose` para confirmar, porque si en vez de usar la primera expresión usa la segunda va a tener un comportamiento no deseado del programa.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n por que no deseado, por el null?

Comment: Exacto, y puede que se espere siempre `true` o `false`. De lo contratio puedes encontrarte con un NullException al usarse en otro sitio. El operador && siempre da uno de los dos casos, nunca dará `null`. Por eso asegurate de qué quieres exactamente. Si pusieras el código que digo quedaría más claro cuál debe ser el comportamiento correcto.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n el OP ya explico eso, encontro esa estructura en un libro, el cual dice que eso retorna un objeto, vino a preguntar si era posible y se fue sabiendo que esa estructura **no retorna un objeto sino un booleano** que mas?

Comment: El OP preguntó si era posible esa construcción y lo es. Si luego cambió la pregunta con un comentario que según dices ha borrado debería editarse para no llevar a confusión a otro que entre a verla porque la solución es distinta a lo que se pide después de leer todo.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n espero que esta edicion aclare todas tus preocupaciones. XD Salu2

Answer (score 0):

Pues parece que sí es posible. Sobrecarga de operadores: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms228498(v=vs.90).aspx

En este caso ambas funciones devuelven una instancia que recibe el operador sobrecargado y crea el objeto.
Aunque no tiene mucho sentido el cortocircuito de &&, claro.

Comment: Ojo que los operadores logicos no pueden sobrecargarse. ver https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8edha89s.aspx

Comment: Del link: "The conditional logical operators cannot be overloaded, but they are evaluated using & and |, which can be overloaded.". Vaya, que no tiene importancia si los quieres llamar lógicos o binarios, al final es lo mismo. El comportamiento lo define la clase.